# Availability table using Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

Is it possible to archive the functionality like this?

[image]

The table schema is:

```
        Schema::create('availability_general', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('day_of_the_week');
        $table->time('from');
        $table->time('to');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve part of that functionality using the `repeatable` field - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#repeatable-1 , not sure if everything though.

But since this interface is so peculiar, I recommend coding your own thing for this bit - you'll be better off. Either by creating a custom field type https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type-1 or a custom operation https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations#documentation-box